# Mirroring sprite object in canvas game. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I got a small problem. I made a 2d small game using canvas and I really wanna know if there is any solution to "fix" my game a little bit. For example, my object moves in any direction using arrow left, up, right, down, but when i turn left, it goes backward, so i wanna know if there is any way of mirroring the image only when i turn left, and when i turn right again to turn back to the initial position. I hope i made myself clear, my english is pretty bad. Here is my souce code: http://justpaste.it/mqpe 
Sorry for the external link. I cant post more than 3 links and i got 3 links in code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/vx3xbuj0/

html

```
<div class="flip-it">
    test
</div>
```

css

```
div{
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
}

.flip-it {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
    filter: FlipH;
}
```

more info http://monkeyraptor.johanpaul.net/2013/07/how-to-mirror-image-using-css3.html

Answer (score 0):

You should make another, mirrored, sprite and then when the left arrow key is pressed change the original sprite with the mirrored.